# fetching intermediate redirect URL

Tags: selenium, testing

How to fetch query parameter from intermediate redirect URL when you land on final URL in selenium.

I need to test whether a certain query param exists in one of the intermediate redirect URLs that are hit before finally I land on a final destination URL in selenium tests. Is there any easy way to pull the redirect URLs or maybe save them as a list?[Example redirects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wQC8.png)

Comment: You can capture network logs and verify that.

Answer (score 0):

Like [Nandan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7731623/nandan-a) suggested, your best option is to capture network logs or use a different tool.

Selenium attempts to interact with the browser the same way an end-user would.  Since an end-user is unlikely to care (or even notice) an intermediate URL, Selenium doesn't really offer a reliable way to check the query params.

When transitioning between pages, in most cases Selenium waits for the page to be fully loaded before it allows your code to interact with it.  This means that it's unlikely anything you *do* try to grab the param (like checking the page URL) will be unsuccessful.

Something you could try is using Selenium's Javascript Executor to check the [referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer).  This might not work; Some pages disable or edit it.  But it's worth a shot.

Wait until your final page is loaded, then use the `execute_script` method (or it's equivalent for your Selenium bindings) to grab the referrer:

`driver.execute_script "return document.referrer"`

Then, use String methods to find your query param.